# Windows explorer showing X on mapped drives but only when

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, application

Hey guys here with another issue.  Its a weird one.

Ok so I have a user who runs a program called Focal Point which send data to our CNC Machines.  I am the IT guy so I have no clue what the machines do or how to use them.

Anyways when the user logs in and launches Focal Point it loses the Access database where the information is stored out on the network.  Windows explorer shows the drives are connection.  However when I open the program and search for the database it does not see the network drive.  I have to do a workaround where I can open something in another part of the program and then when the windows explorer window comes up the drives all show disconnected.  I double click on a drive and it opens just fine.  I then go back to point the program to the database and it shows that drive as an option now.

I don't know what is happening but Symantec does it too.  When I go to add an exception it shows my drives are disconnected but I can access them fine and when I do the X goes away until the next logoff or reboot.

However in programs like Office, when I go to open a document with Word, the drives do not have a red X.  I will attach screenshots of what I am talking about.

This is the programs built in explorer.  Cant see network drive[image: Built in Explorer in program]

This is explorer straight form windows

[image]

I have to go to another section to find the drive through windows explorer in the program but drives have an X

[image]

I click on a drive and it turns green and connected.  Rest show disconnected.  The program explorer now shows the network drive (drive S):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx

This solved my issue.  As soon as I made the registry entry the drives were showing up as connected in the program and I did not have to reconfigure it.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem for you - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/297684.

it's caused by the drives disconnecting after a period of inactivity. The knowledge base article provides a fix to stop it happening.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a symbolic link?

mklink /d "c:\data\network docs" "\server\shareddata\"

That way you're not depending on the network drive

Comment: I have not but since multiple users use the network drive and everything launches from a script at login I do not want to change the script